# When I smoke my cigarettes why do I feel smart?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

I dunno why I feel smart after getting some smokes in.

Answer (score 7):

My only possible suggestion is that nicotine helps memory function see 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_improvement scroll  down where it says about nicotine.

Nevertheless if you want to improve your brain agility and memory or at least stay healthy I don't suggest starting smoking it will affect your body including mind negatively in numerous ways and then will affect your temper as well( http://www.gizmag.com/smoking-found-to-affect-brain/17240/ and millions of other sources can be found ).

In my opinion is interesting to see the benefits of nicotine but if so the best way would be with a some kind of a special field doctor giving you the appropriate amount of it and monitoring you how dieticians do.